# 80s-90s sci-fi cartoon: boy (Cony? Koney?) fights against an evil emperor of sorts, and searches for his kidnapped father

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

My older brother and I have been trying to remember this show for years. We don't know if it was aired in the 80's or 90's since we had an episode or two recorded on VHS and we were both pretty young.

All we can remember is a boy searching for his father (and probably more of his friends and family) who have been kidnapped by the big bad guy. He was being kept prisoner on a spaceship which, at the end of the episode, took off into space and escaped the protagonist and his allies.

My brother seems to recall the name "Cony" or "Koney" or some variation thereof being involved, but my searching has not yielded any results so it might not be related.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and answer as many of those questions as you can, editing the answers into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be the [*Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayce_and_the_Wheeled_Warriors) (1985)? In this series they are in their search for Jayce's father. Meanwhile, they are fighting against the Saw Boss and his followers.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0217941/):

> In a distant galaxy where magic and technology co-exist, Audric, a scientist, accidentally creates The Monster Minds, a race of mutated plant creatures that goes on a rampage and sets out to take over the universe. In a bid to correct the creation of The Monster Minds, Audric creates a plant called "The Magic Root" which will destroy The Monster Minds, but The Magic Root got split into two pieces and half of the magic root is given to Audric's son Jayce. Joined by a team of fighters known as "The Lightning League" led by a 1000-year-old wizard named Gillian, Jayce embarks on a desperate quest to find his father and put the two pieces of "The Magic Roots" together, which will destroy The Monster Minds and their evil leader, Sawboss, who will try and stop Jayce and Audric from destroying them and stop them from dominating the galaxy.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayce_and_the_Wheeled_Warriors#List_of_characters), there is a "space barge"; however this was operated by the Lightning League, not the Monster Minds.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should take the [tour]!  This answer is a bit thin on detail;  you should note specifically how your answer matches the details in the question.  Check out the [answer] guide.